# How to restrict a vcenter user to only one resoure pool? with complete access to that resoure pool

Tags: permissions, vmware

I have been trying all permutations and combinations of the required privileges to be assigned to a role that have access to only one resource pool.

My Requirement is that i have 2 ESXI hosts(not clustered) and have more than 100vms inside it. in ESX1 host i have created a resource pool for the newly joined interns.

1. i want the interns to have access to only one resource pool. he can create remove VMS from that resource pool.
2. He should not be able to see any other vms/hosts apart from his resource pool.

what i have done and failed to achieve.

1. created group "interns" created users inter1..10 and added the intern users to "interns" group.
2. Created a role "new_interns" and added the group "interns". note: the role
   "new_interns" was cloned form "Resource pool administrator".
3. added permission for "new_interns" group at each level from Vcenter->datacenter->host->resource pool ( but have not propagated to child because when i propagate the user is able to see VM/host outside the resource pool)

Kindly provide me any information related to this.